# Redirect all requests to a subdirectory using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a subdomain `http://www.sub.example.com` but the index file is not in the root directory but instead it is `project/example/index.html` and some of it's dependencies are there and in the parent directory `project/`. How can I make it so that users visiting http://www.sub.example.com are able to access the website?

I have tried setting a DirectoryIndex like so:

```
DirectoryIndex project/example/index.html
```

But all of my images, scripts, and styles return a 404.

So I tried to rewrite like so:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/project/example/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/example/$1 [NC,L]
```

Which fixes my styles and images (which are in `projects/example/` directory). However, all of my other dependencies in the parent `project/` directory are still missing. Is there a way to include them?

Example index.html dependency in parent directory:

```
<script src="../node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>

<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Where is `styles.css` located?

Comment: It is located in the same directory as index.html (`project/example`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this **just below `<head>` tag** of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/project/example/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: Thank you! Just an FYI I had to add a slash to the end (Ex: `<base href="/project/example/" />`) for it to work, I also had to remove RewriteEngine, RewriteCond, RewriteRule from my .htaccess while leaving only the DirectoryIndex condition.